# Assign combinations of conditions to a new column in a dataframe through dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I am trying to use a combinations of dictionaries to generate a conditional column in a dataframe.

The first dictionary contains a list of all possible conditions which results in a bool `True` or `False`.

The second dictionary assigns combinations of conditions to business rules I want to call in order to generate a conditional column in my dataframe.

```
# testing df
d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': ['apple', 'pear', 'banana', 'apple', 'cookie']}

# making the df
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# all possible testing conditions
df_conds = {
    1: eval("df['col1'] == 3"),
    2: eval("df['col1'] >= 3"),
    3: eval("df['col2'] == 'apple'")
}

# assigning combinations of conditions to business rules
df_cond_assignments = {
    'br1' : [1, 2],
    'br2' : [1, 2, 3],
    'br3' : [3],
    'br4' : [2, 3]
}
```

I want to call `br4` for instance, and generate my conditional column by applying conditions 2 and 3.

```
result_df['result'] = df_conds[df_cond_assignments.get('br4')]
```

That code results in `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` and I understand why. However, I'm not sure how to do what I'm trying to do.

Another way I tried was

```
result_df = df_conds.get(key for key in [df_cond_assignments.get('br4')])
```

Which returns `None`

For example, if I apply `br4` the correct result would look like:

```
result:
false
false
false
true
false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work for you:

```
np.logical_and.reduce([df_conds[i] for i in df_cond_assignments['br4']])
```

Output:

```
array([False, False, False,  True, False])
```

Comment: This is brilliant. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Whitewater Thank you.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.